# Count the number of times values change in a series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Consider the series:

```
s = [1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1]
```

What is the most time-efficient way to count the number of times values in such series change? In this example, the answer is 3 (from 1 to -1, back to 1, and again to -1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will using `numpy`

```
(np.diff(s)!=0).sum()
Out[497]: 3
```

Comment: So concise and perfect. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution using `numpy` is

```
np.count_nonzero(np.diff(s))
```

A native Python solution is

```
sum(s[i - 1] != s[i] for i in range(1, len(s)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I will go with this, Correct me if wrong..! :)

```
# This will append 1 in list if change occurs
c = [1 for i,x in enumerate(s[:-1]) if x!= s[i+1] ]  
# Printing the length of list which is ultimately the total no. of change
print(len(c))
```

[image]