# How to calculate the element total change times in an ArrayList

Tags: java, list, algorithm, arraylist

the scenario is I have a class as below,

```
@Data
class Operation
{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

and an ArrayList which contains lots of Operation instances.

For example, there're five instance in the ArrayList,

```
{"id":"0001", "name":"up"}
{"id":"0002", "name":"down"}
{"id":"0003", "name":"left"}
{"id":"0004", "name":"left"}
{"id":"0005", "name":"up"}
```

I want to know how many times the name changed in the ArrayList, in this case, the second name is down, it is different with the first one, the change times is 1, the third name is also different with the sceond name, then the change times is 2, but the fourth name as same as the third one, so the change times is still 2, the fifth is different with the fourth, so the change times of this ArrayList is 3.

Is there a way to calculate it without traverse the ArrayList?

Comment: Perhaps there's a way of counting while you're populating the ArrayList, but there's no way of doing It without traversing the ArrayList.

Comment: You can traverse the the list and keep checking the current name value with previous name which takes O(n) time, which is better in many cases. But, without traversing the list, it would be difficult(or not possible maybe)

Comment: Related: [Count the number of times values change in a series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56509717/count-the-number-of-times-values-change-in-a-series) (I know it’s Python, but I swear that most ideas can be used in Java too). Please search for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    List<Operation> operations = List.of(
            new Operation("0001", "up"),
            new Operation("0002", "down"),
            new Operation("0003", "left"),
            new Operation("0004", "left"),
            new Operation("0005", "up"));
    
    // Don’t include index 0 since it has no previous name to compare with
    long numberOfNameChanges = IntStream.range(1, operations.size())
            .filter(i -> ! operations.get(i - 1).getName()
                    .equals(operations.get(i).getName()))
            .count();
    
    System.out.println("Count is " + numberOfNameChanges);
```

Output is:

> Count is 3

And it does traverse the list.

For the sake of a complete example I used `List.of()` (since Java 9) rather than `ArrayList`, but the stream operation will work just as well with `ArrayList` too.

I generally say that stream operations don’t work well when operations on more list elements are involved. This seems to be the exception; I find the stream solution just fine myself. If you prefer, you can code it with a loop instead.

PS I’m not very fond of giving working code away when you haven’t shown that much of an effort on your part. Only I found this was easier to explain with code, so I compromised.

**Edit**

> how about we collect set of the values …

No, that won’t work. I give two examples to show you. The simpler one first, I have just removed the final `up` from your list so there are only 2 value changes:

```
    List<Operation> operations = List.of(
            new Operation("0001", "up"),
            new Operation("0002", "down"),
            new Operation("0003", "left"),
            new Operation("0004", "left"));
    
    Set<String> collect = operations.stream()
            .map(operation -> operation.name.toLowerCase())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    
    System.out.println(collect);
```

> [left, up, down]

Even when I have removed one value change, there are still 3 elements in the set. You may tihnk that you can just subtract 1. Not so. Look at the next and last example:

```
    List<Operation> operations = List.of(
            new Operation("0001", "up"),
            new Operation("0003", "left"),
            new Operation("0002", "up"),
            new Operation("0003", "left"),
            new Operation("0004", "left"));
```

Now there are three value changes but only two elements in the set:

> [left, up]

And if you subtracted 1, you’d end up with 1.

As you may have realized by now, the problem with the `Set` approach is it doesn’t take into account when the same name appears again later causing a new value change.

Comment: Hi Ole, i am following your answer, how about we collect set of the values like
`Set<String> collect = operations.stream()
                .map(operation -> operation.name.toLowerCase())
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Comment: Sorry, @silentsudo, that won’t work. It sounded like a nice and simple idea. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

When you use if(setEvent(index,object)) For exmaple you can make from that event like if(object == "meow) return true; return false;
and if is true it will set if not will not.

You can use abstract class for add events(listener)

```
public abstract class MyList<Object> {

private ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

public void set(int index,Object object){
    if(setEvent(index,object)) list.set(index,object);
}

public void add(Object object){
    if(addEvent(object)) list.add(object);
}

public void remove(Object object){
    if(removeEvent(object)) list.remove(object);
}

public void remove(int index){
    if(removeEvent(index)) list.remove(index);
}

public Object get(int index){
    if(getEvent(index)) return list.get(index);
    return null;
}

public void clear(){
    if(clearEvent()) list.clear();
}

//Abstract

public abstract boolean setEvent(int index, Object object);

public abstract boolean addEvent(Object object);

public abstract boolean removeEvent(Object object);

public abstract boolean removeEvent(int index);

public abstract boolean getEvent(int index);

public abstract boolean clearEvent();

}
```

Comment: First off all, what value does this solution add? Could you please explain it in words? And why use Object, why not a generic solution instead?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to calculate it without traverse the ArrayList?

No.

To look at each value in a list, and compare to the adjacent value, requires traversing the list. There is no magic shortcut.